# How to prototype with an 8-pin 'daughter board'

Tags: prototyping, breadboard

I've purchased a couple of wireless transciever boards (nRF24L01), and they bring out the I/O pins in an 2x4 arrangement which fits snuggly into breadboard. However (obviously) when you do that the pins are 'connected'!

I think I need to take a breadboard apart and break some tracks.

Without soldering, is this my only option?

Any other approaches appreciated.

Many thanks
Ian Hunter

Comment: I don't see any 'obviousness' in your statements. What transceiver board are you using? What type of breadboard? The only reference you've provided is to a certain QFN-20 IC. Please provide some more details.

Comment: @mad I see plenty of obviousness.  The issue is with the connector as described - the rest of the daughterboard is irrelevant.

Comment: Why don't you want to solder?  Are you trying to avoid damaging the transceiver boards, trying to avoid extra work, or lacking soldering equipment entirely?

Comment: @Matt Breadboard can mean many things: those white plastic boards with spring clips inside them, bare FR4 boards with holes for wire-wrapping, partially-plated FR4 boards, boards with traces between the pads. To me, it wasn't clear that he meant he was using a white plastic breadboard and the 2x4 pins were connected *to each other* (i.e. shorted) by insertion.

Comment: Breadboard is the white plastic.  Matrix board is the FR4.

Comment: Breadboard is certainly a more generic term as well as a verb.

Answer (score 4):

Get the mating 2x4 pin connector, then make up a cable that ends in 8 wires you can stick into the breadboard anywhere you want.  You could even solder them to a DIP header, which can be easily plugged onto the breadboard.

How are you going to connect to this 2x4 pin header in the final product?  If you're going to plug it into a socket as intended, then use another socket to make a breadboard adapter.  If it's a one-off and you plan to solder to the 2x4 pin header, then you might as well solder wires to it for breadboard use now.

I don't understand the requirement to not solder.  Soldering is simple, quick, reasonably reliable, and can also be easily undone.  If you don't want to get solder on the header pins, what about soldering to the bottom of the pins on the other side of the board, assuming the header is thru hole?  If it's SMD, then there should be pins running out from the connector you can solder thin wires to.  At .1" spacing you've got lots of room, so it should be easy.

Comment: Thanks for your input Olin. I think the plug & 8 cables is the way forward.

Answer (score 3):

Personally for a situation like this I would make a little breakout board that spreads the pins out for you.  Just 2 rows of 4 pins in a board, with 2 rows of 4 sockets - you could use simple stripboard - then you wouldn't need to ruin your breadboard.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Essentially I'm trying to avoid soldering because a) I'm lazy b) I'm not in the right environment to make a mess. I think I'll fix both, and knock up a simple adapter. I guess I was hoping for a 'get one of these from a catalog' solution :-)

Comment: Maybe I'll add one to my catalog ;)